# I am getting this error, RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 2. How do I fix it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

This is the exact error I am getting.
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 2
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<List>

The widget the error is referencing:

```
StreamBuilder<List<QuestionDbRecord>>(
                              stream: queryQuestionDbRecord(
                                queryBuilder: (questionDbRecord) =>
                                    questionDbRecord.where('questionid',
                                        isEqualTo: quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecord.questionList[2]),
                                singleRecord: true,
                              ),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return Center(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 50,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                        size: 50,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
```

QuestionDbRecord is a collection on firestore. It has a field called questionid which I use to get the exact question document that I need.

questionList is a list of four questionid's. The third of which I am using to get the question I need.

It would be really nice if you could be specific with where I went wrong, because my dumbass will otherwise spend an hour trying to get what you were trying to say.

Code snippet where quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecord has been initialized. The code for the entire page is quite long so let me know if more information could be required.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<TopicRecommendationsRecord>>(
      stream: queryTopicRecommendationsRecord(
        queryBuilder: (topicRecommendationsRecord) => topicRecommendationsRecord
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUserReference)
            .where('topicName', isEqualTo: widget.topicName),
        singleRecord: true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                size: 50,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        List<TopicRecommendationsRecord>
            quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecordList = snapshot.data;
        // Customize what your widget looks like with no query results.
        if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('No results.'),
            ),
          );
        }
        final quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecord =
            quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecordList.first;
        return Scaffold(
```

Comment: Where is `quizpageMcqTopicRecommendationsRecord` coming from? Can you post the full screen?

Comment: Hey @VictorEronmosele I have added it now. The full screen is 1000+ lines of code